# symfony sonata admin roles on embedded onetomany entities

Tags: symfony, one-to-many, roles, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I have *Symfony 2.3 + Sonata Admin + Sonata User Bundle*.

I have created an entity `Student`, and another entity `Contact`. An `Student` have one-to-many relationship with `Contact`. I have added `Contact` to `Student` with `sonata_type_collection` in my `StudentAdmin` class. I also have created a group of users `Operator` and assigned all permissions to `Student`, but only `list` and `view` to `Contact`.

My problem is that any user of `Operator` can't add or delete `Contact` (from Student edit page), but they can edit (and values are saved).

Any suggestions or examples?

Some code:

Roles assigned:

```
ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_STUDENT_EDIT
ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_STUDENT_LIST
ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_STUDENT_CREATE
ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_STUDENT_VIEW
ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_STUDENT_DELETE 

ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_CONTACT_LIST
ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_CONTACT_VIEW 

ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN 


     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Contact",
                      mappedBy="student",
                      cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     **/
    private $contact;


->add('contact', 'sonata_type_collection',
                    array(
                            'label' => 'Contact',
                            'by_reference' => false,
                    ),
                    array(
                            'edit' => 'inline',
                            'inline' => 'table',
                    ))
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? You want User with role Operator to add / delete contact ? you have to add the roles ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_CONTACT_CREATE, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_CONTACT_DELETE

Comment: English is not my language maybe i have misspelled something.
With roles that i assign, when i'm in student edit page, Operator user cannot add or delete contact (in embedded form), that's ok, because buttons add/delete disappears, but he can edit/change values (added previously by users with access), because the inputs are enabled, and when I save Student, the values are persisted to contact. I don't want that. I have other group of users for that.
I think that the problem is to know how roles work with related/embedded entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood your problem and I don't think Sonata handle this by default.

You have to check the current user roles and either remove contact fields or add readonly or disabled attribute on the contact fields.

**Remove Contact Fields**

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    // check if current user has role contact edition
    $hasContactRole = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_CONTACT_EDIT'));
    if ($hasContactRole) {
        $formMapper->add('contact', 'sonata_type_collection',
            array(
                'label' => 'Contact',
                'by_reference' => false,
            ),
            array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your time. It's an elegant solution and it open my mind on how to cover areas not covered by Symfony/Sonata.

Comment: You should accept my answer if it fixed your problem, so it rewards my work and help people with similar issues, that's how StackOverflow works ;)
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow